# SSRS 2008 -- link to external website

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My company is using SSRS 2008 for reporting services and there are 100's of different reports in it. After using SSRS 2008 for some charts we decided to to no use SSRS for charting and decided to use an open source javascript library to display charts. The main reason was to have some interactive charts!

I have now done a few charts in this open source library which itself is a asp.net webapp and have deployed it. I am wondering is there a way to add "links" to SSRS 2008 so when they are clicked user is redirected to this charts application. The main reason is to have one single area where employees will go for reports and charts.

I was thinking of creating an empty RDL file and on some 'onload' event just do a redirect but I have been unable to find if these reports fire any events!

Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the field you want to direct to your charting system, click `Text Box Properties...` and click `Action`. You want the `Go to URL` option, which you can use to enter a URL to redirect to.

Note that you can use expressions here to assist in going to the right chart, for example:

```
="http://mycharts/regionchart?Id=" & Fields!Region.Value
```